# Facebook will not save my private policy URL

Tags: facebook, url, private, policy

I am making an app for Facebook. When I enter my privacy policy and terms addresses into the blocks and hit save, the page just goes blank. I have looked everywhere I know to look, but still cannot find an answer. I am using http://www.quatrodesigns.hostzi.com/privacy.html/ it works fine when I type it into a browser. I do not understand why it will not accept it. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The URL `hostzi.com` has been blocked for being spammy or unsafe. If you own or manage this domain, go to https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=244560538958131 to appeal the block.

Note, I discovered this by trying to share the URL on my wall, which was prevented by Facebook's spam blocking tools.